# understanding trifecta parser <|> and try

Tags: haskell, trifecta

While reading Haskell book I came across [trifecta](https://github.com/ekmett/trifecta)

I'm trying to wrap my head around but still not able to understand <|>

**I have following questions.**

in simple words (<|>) = Monadic Choose  ?

**p = a <|> b** -- use parser *a* if not then use *b* ?

if yes then why following parser is failing ?

```
parseFraction :: Parser Rational
parseFraction = do
    numerator <- decimal
    char '/'
    denominator <- decimal
    case denominator of 
        0 -> fail "denominator cannot be zero"
        _ -> return (numerator % denominator)


type RationalOrDecimal = Either Rational Integer
parseRationalOrDecimal = (Left <$> parseFraction) <|> (Right<$> decimal)


main = do
    let p f i = parseString f mempty i
    print $ p (some (skipMany (oneOf "\n")  *> parseRationalOrDecimal <* skipMany (oneOf "\n"))) "10"
```

in perfect world if a is **parseFraction** is going to fail then `<|>` should go with **decimal** but this is not the case.
but when I use try it works.

1. what I'm missing ?
2. why we need to use *try* when <|> should run second parser on first failure ?

`parseRationalOrDecimal = try (Left <$> parseFraction) <|> (Right<$> decimal)`

Comment: I don't know about trifecta in particular, but in other parser combinator libraries there are sometimes two kinds of failure. There is "failure that consumes input" and "failure that does not consume input". In those libraries, `a <|> b` only tries `b` if `a` is a failure that does not consume input; and `try x` fails without consuming input whenever `x` fails and consumes input. Perhaps that is what is happening here.

Comment: @DanielWagner
means we have to wrap try for every parser ? `try  a <|> try b <|> try c | d`  is it a good idea ? what about `d` the last one ?

Comment: In general, you should structure a parser so that it fails as early as possible (when success is not possible), so that the time wasted in `try`ing is small. Overuse of `try` can lead to horrible performance e.g. `expression = try addition <|> try subtraction <|> multiplication` where each case also recurses in `expression`. One usually needs to refactor the grammar, a bit like in LL(1) parsing, so to avoid performance issues. In your case, `try` looks OK since the parser runs for only a few chars, anyway.

Comment: @hanan Of course, you don't actually have to write that out if you have a large number of alternatives. An equivalent way to write that would be `asum . map try $ [a, b, c, d]`. But fundamentally, yes, if you want each alternative to be able to backtrack after consuming input, you need a `try` around each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is beacuse `parseFraction` consumes input before failing therefore, it is considered to be the correct branch in the choice. Let me give you and example:

Let say you are writing a python parser and you have to decide if a declaration is a `class` or a function (keyword `def`), then you write

```
parseExpresion = word "def" <|> word "class" -- DISCLAIMER: using a ficticious library
```

Then if the user writes `def` or `class` it will match, but if the user writes `det` It will try the first branch and match `de` and then fail to match expected `f` because `t` was found. It will not bother to try the next parser, because the error is considered to be in the first branch. It'd make little sense to try the `class` parser since likely, the error is in the first branch.

In your case `parseFraction` matches some digits and then fails because `/` isn't found, and then it doesn't bother to try `decimal` parser.

This is a desing decision, some other libraries use a different convention (ex: `Attoparsec` always backtrack on failure), and some functions claim to "not consume input" (ex: `notFollowedBy`)

Notice that there is a trade-off here:

**First**: If `<|>` behaves as you expect the following

```hs
parse parseRationalOrDecimal "123456789A"
```

will first parse all numbers until "A" is found and then it will parse **again!** all numbers until "A" is found... so doing the same computation twice just to return a failure.

**Second**: If you care more about error messages the current behaviour is more convinient. Following the python example, imagine:

```
parseExpresion = word "def" <|> word "class" <|> word "import" <|> word "type" <|> word "from"
```

If the user types "frmo" the, the parser will go to the last branch and will raise and error like `expected "from" but "frmo" was found` Whereas, if all alternatives must be checked the error would be something more like `expected one of "def", "class", "import", "type" of "from"` which is less close to the actual typo.

As I said, it is a library desing decision, I am just trying to convince you that there are good reasons to not try all alternatives automatically, and use `try` if you explicitly want to do so.